# howt to get all value from json result in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift3

I have tier to get all value from this jsonResult i want array from this   like "projectArray","msg","msg2" and string like "output" ,"output_prg" i only get first array value how to get other values?

**This is my result**

```
{
    "project": [{
        "name": [{
            "sac": "sachin",
            "sag": "sagar"
        }]
    }, {
        "output": " true",
        "msg1": [{
            "emp": "001",
            "empname": "sachin"
        }, {
            "emp": "002",
            "empname": "sagar"
        }]
    }, {
        "output_prg": " true",
        "msg2": [{
            "id": "1",
            "pr_code": "SD"
        }, {
            "id": "002",
            "pr_code": "SJ"
        }]
    }]
 }
```

**This is my code**

```
 if let array = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
            {
                print(array)
                let mainArray = array["project"] as? [[String:Any]]
                print(mainArray!)

                for item in mainArray!
                {
                    print(item)
                    let status = item["name"]
                    print(status!)

                }
}
```

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try This---->**

```
            //to get JSON return value
            if let array = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
            {
                print(array)
                let mainArray = array["project"] as? [[String:Any]]
                print(mainArray?.count as Any)

                if (mainArray?.count)!>0
                {
                    let name = mainArray?[0]
                    let project_status = name?["name"] as? [[String:Any]]
                    print(name!)
                }
                if (mainArray?.count)!>1
                {
                    let output = mainArray?[1]

                    print(output!)
                }
                if (mainArray?.count)!>2
                {
                    let output_prg = mainArray?[2]
                    let Output_getProject = output_prg?["output_prg"]

                    }

                }

            }
```

**Happy Coading :-)**